# Is scroll behavior coming from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you look at the following page: https://www.a1.digital/sdwan

If you scroll down the page to

> Berechnen Sie hier Ihre Ersparnis mit SD-WAN

Below it you will see a form. Leave the form as is, do not fill anything in and click on the big red submit button that says the following on it:

> Kostenlos präzise Berechnung des Einsparungspotentials anfordern

You will see that the page will automatically scroll down to the first required element of that form which has not been filled out. However I cannot identify where this behavior is coming from.

I need to add an offset to the scrolling as the form fields are being covered by the fixed nav when the browser scrolls to the first required input field.

Comment: `You will see that the page will automatically scroll down to the first required element of that form which has not been filled out. ` strange it doesn't do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `required` attribute on the html input element. Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) for more info.

The "scrolling" is done by the browser itself.

Comment: Can I add an offset to the scrolling ?

Comment: No, as I said, this is done by the browser. The problem on your website is the top overlay covering the form. Maybe you should look into fixing this instead.